# Combining flat file modification and concatenating steps

Tags: bash, shell

I perform this operation very often, and I am looking for a shortcut. Is there any way I can do the following without having to write to a temp file?

```
cut -k 3-5 file1 > temp1
cat temp1 file2 | sort > outfile
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the data look like that you're operating on (i.e. the data in file1 and file2)?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
cut -k 3-5 file1 | cat - file2 | sort > outfile
```

There may be ancient versions of `cat` which do not take `-` to mean standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Just do them in sequence:

```
(cut -k 3-5 file1; cat file2) | sort > outfile
```

This has the added advantage of working in any Bourne-based shell without requiring bash- or zsh-specific features.

Comment: Awesome. I can edit both files if I wish to do so... I didn't realize you can perform actions in sequence as such in bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
cat <(cut -k 3-5 file1) file2 | sort > outfile
```

Comment: Although this is just another way to make a temp file (or possibly a named pipe).

Comment: This seems to work, but it is difficult for me to remember. Thanks for another good solution! :)